# Jekyll --server not working

Tags: ruby, jekyll

I am having an issue when I try to run Jekyll --server locally. I am getting the following errors that I am having trouble deciphering:

```
/Users/jgindi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in 'require': iconv will be deprecated in the future, use String#encode instead.
Configuration from /Users/jgindi/Desktop/Codestuffs/julian25.github.com/_config.yml
/Users/jgindi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/directory_watcher-1.4.1/lib/directory_watcher/em_scanner.rb:10:in `block in <top (required)>': undefined method 'kqueue' for EventMachine:Module (NoMethodError)
```

I do not understand what the issue is?

Comment: Can you post your _config.yml? You don't appear to be using the `--auto` option so I don't know why you'd get an error from directory watcher.

Comment: Here is my _config.yml:

  markdown: rdiscount
  pygments: true
  permalink: /posts/:title
  auto: true
  rdiscount:
   extensions: [smart]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using RVM, create a new gemset for your blog and make sure you do **not** install eventmachine in that gemset. Eventmachine support in directory_watcher is experimental. When I created a blank gemset with your blog source code from GitHub, I couldn't reproduce the error you're seeing.

Answer (score 1):

This could be that you already have something running on your local host

Enter this in terminal

```
lsof -i TCP:3000
```

The `3000` is the port number your using, so could be `4000` for example.

It will return something like this

```
joshuahornby ~/workspace/myBlog/ (master) 
→ lsof -i TCP:3000
COMMAND  PID   USER       FD     TYPE     DEVICE     SIZE/OFF    NODE   NAME
ruby   68780   renaebair   6u    IPv4     0x10898278     0t0      TCP     *:hbci (LISTEN)
```

Grab the process number (a.k.a. PID) (in this case it was 68780) and then type “kill #{that_pid}”:

```
kill 68780
```

Then try to connect to the --server

Comment: I tried using the code listed above but nothing showed up for port 3000, or 4000.

Comment: What port have you been using to run jekyll on? Thats the port you should use. For example I use jekyll --server 4000 --auto  You may use 1000. Its just the port number you use.

Answer (score 0):

Some of this could be due to an older eventmachine version.

I ran into this when I had eventmachine-0.12.10.  Reinstalling eventmachine brought me to 1.0.3 and jekyll started fine after that.